# How to make a function to analyse a sentence?

Tags: function-construction, map

I have two lists:

```
grammarNonterminal = {{VP,{V,NP}},{NP,{D,N}},{S,{NP,VP}}}
sentence = {{D,"the"},{N,"man"},{V,"hit"},{D,"the"},{N,"table"}}
```

I want to make a function which changes `sentence` into the followings when the function takes `grammarNonterminal` and `sentence` as arguments.

```
⇒  {{NP, {D, "the"}, {N,"man"}}, {V, "hit"}, {D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}} , {{{D, "the"}, {N, "man"}, {V, "hit"}, {NP, {{D, "the"}, {N, “table"}}},

⇒  {{NP, {D, "the"}, {N, "man"}}, {V, "hit"}, {NP, {D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}}},{{D, "the"}, {N, "man"}, {VP, {{V, "hit"}, {NP, {D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}}

⇒ {{{NP, {D, "the"}, {N, "man"}}, {VP, {{V, "hit"}, {NP, {{D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}}}}

⇒ {{{S, {NP, {D, "the"}, {N, "man"}}, {VP, {{V, "hit"}, {NP, {{D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}}}}}
```

I know I have to use `ReplaceList`, `Map` and `Union` to achieve this.

Is there a simple way to do this?

---

What I wanted to do is something like below.

First, you make a function `applyRule`:

```
applyRule[sentence_, r_] := ReplaceList[sentence,{x___,c : Apply[PatternSequence, {#, _} & /@ r[[2]] ], y___} -> {x, ReplacePart[r, 2 -> {c}], y}];

r = {NP,{D,N}} 

applyRule[sentence,r] = {{{NP, {{D, "the"}, {N, "man"}}}, {V, "hit"}, {D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}, {{D,"the"}, {N, "man"}, {V, "hit"}, {NP, {{D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}}}}
```

And then make a function to change `sentence` into

```
{{{S, {NP, {D, "the"}, {N, "man"}}, {VP, {{V, "hit"}, {NP, {{D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}}}}}
```

by using `applyRule`, `Map`, and `Union`.

I tried

```
Union[Map[applyRule[sentence, #] &, grammarNonterminal]
```

but this doesn't give me the result that I want.

Comment: I *really* think this requires more explanation. We need at least a set of rules for the replacements. Why, for instance, does the second sequence of `D, word, N, word` get replaced first, then only later the other one? How do we specify the *order* in which terms get replaced? Must it happen from the end of the sentence backward? Probably not, because eventually, the `D, word, N, word` at the beginning of the sentence gets replaced, but that's only after nothing else can be replaced. Anyway, more info please!

Comment: Also: a comment about usage. Do *not* use capital letters for symbols,  because all built-in *Mathematica* functions start with capital letters. You already have problems because both `D` and `N` have built-in *Mathematica* meanings. I recommend using `vp`, `np`, `d`, `v`, and `n`.

Comment: Wait wait! A couple of things! First, don't be so hasty to accept! This kind of question (if more information is included) can attract more answers, and *better* answers since there are a lot of *Mathematica* experts here who might actually have domain knowledge relevant to this problem, but people tend to avoid already accepted answers. Second, please answer the questions I had if you can! Third, it is considered bad form to accept without upvoting (I'm not sure by whom other than me, but anyway).

Comment: @march Thanks for pointing those out. I'm new to Mathematica and here and I mixed up "accept" with "upvoting". For the order, it does't necessarily have to be like that as long as you get `{{{S, {NP, {D, "the"}, {N, "man"}}, {VP, {{V, "hit"}, {NP, {{D, "the"}, {N, "table"}}}}}}` in the end. I just edited the question to add some explanations.

Comment: This might be overkill for the type of problem you want to tackle, but I have code [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/388/) for a top-down (LL) parser, applied to sentences from a simple grammar.

Answer (score 9):

Anyway, despite all of my comments, here's my best go at this problem. It's not general, and it doesn't exactly match your syntax, so perhaps someone else will come along and fix it, but this is at least a good start.

I've taken the liberty of changing your notation in a number of ways.

- Lower-case letters for the parts-of-speech.
- Instead of `{d, "the"}` I will use `d["the"]`.

---

Let's define our parser as the following (neatened up per a comment from [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods)):

```
parseList[sentence_] := Delete[FixedPointList[
    # /. {
      {a___, x : PatternSequence[_np, _vp], b___} :> {a, s[x], b},
      {a___, x : PatternSequence[_v, _np], b___} :> {a, vp[x], b},
      {a___, x : PatternSequence[_d, _n], b___} :> {a, np[x], b}
     } &
    , sentence
   ]
   , -1]
```

Due to the way that `ReplaceAll` works, once it replaces an entire expression, it doesn't replace sub-expressions of that expression. I'm taking advantage of that to replace one thing at a time so that we can get out a list of steps. I have also made the more *global* rules first; for instance, the rule that puts together the whole sentence comes first in the list. Finally, we use `FixedPointList` in order to replace phrases in this sentence until it doesn't change anymore.

If you don't care about the steps taken to get to the end, we can instead use `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
parse[sentence_] := sentence //. {
   {a___, x : PatternSequence[_np, _vp], b___} :> {a, s[x], b},
   {a___, x : PatternSequence[_v, _np], b___} :> {a, vp[x], b},
   {a___, x : PatternSequence[_d, _n], b___} :> {a, np[x], b}
  } // First
```

The sentence is

```
sentence = {d["the"], n["man"], v["hit"], d["the"], n["table"]};
```

Then,

```
parSen = parse[sentence]
(* s[np[d["the"], n["man"]], vp[v["hit"], np[d["the"], n["table"]]]] *)
```

or

```
(list = parseList[sentence]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

It doesn't exactly do things in exactly the order you requested, but it gets this simple job done.

The nice thing about this particular syntax (e.g. using `d["the"]` instead of `{d, "the"}`) is that we can display the final parsed sentence in a nice `TreeForm`:

```
TreeForm@parSen
```

[image]

Comment: This is a neat approach. Your rules could be written more concisely by naming the pattern sequence, e.g. `{a___, x : PatternSequence[_d, _n], b___} :> {a, np[x], b}`

Comment: @SimonWoods. Yes absolutely! That is certainly neater. I will add it to the post.